# Add months equal to a field value to another field

Tags: mysql, date, dateinterval

I'm trying to write a query to extract the rows "not expired"

I have a database with a table in which are there :

```
IdActivity    lifespan (months)
```

And another table in which I have:

```
IdSubject    IdActivity    StartDate
```

Now I want to extract all IdSubject with not expired yet activity

I need something like (I know it's wrong: it's only to make clear what I want):

```
SELECT IdSubject FROM Tab2 INNER JOIN Tab1 USING(IdActivity)
WHERE DATEADD(StartDate, INTERVAL lifespan MONTS)>NOW()
```

I made many attempts but nothing worked!

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can't you save expire date instead of lifespan? Then you can easily compare startdate with expiredate.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the opposite and reversing thought I solved: `SELECT IdSubject FROM Tab2 INNER JOIN Tab1 USING(IdActivity)
WHERE StartDate > NOW - INTERVAL (Select lifespan ......) MONTH `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were *really* close - just one character wrong: Use `< NOW()` instead of `> NOW()` to find expired dates.

```
SELECT IdSubject
FROM Tab2
JOIN Tab1 USING(IdActivity)
WHERE DATE_ADD(StartDate, INTERVAL lifespan MONTH) < NOW()
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6081/1)

Comment: You were really close too ;-)

Comment: Maybe it's my fault but I can't make it work in this way. In any case I solved as I wrote in a comment to my post. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Strawberry missing the underscore? :)

Comment: @genespos Well, follow the link to the SQLFiddle to see this query working (note that there was a minor error in my initial version).